# Is ruby whitespace sensitive in certain cases?

Tags: ruby, syntax

A single space affects the value returned by `*`:

```
rand * 10 #=> 2.7177010707339146
rand *10  #=> 1
```

I tried to use Ripper to check the tokens produced by those two expressions.

```
Ripper.lex 'rand *10'
#=> [[[1, 0], :on_ident, "rand", EXPR_CMDARG],
#   [[1, 4], :on_sp, " ", EXPR_CMDARG],
#   [[1, 5], :on_op, "*", EXPR_BEG],
#   [[1, 6], :on_int, "10", EXPR_END|EXPR_ENDARG]]
Ripper.lex 'rand * 10'
#=> [[[1, 0], :on_ident, "rand", EXPR_CMDARG],
#   [[1, 4], :on_sp, " ", EXPR_CMDARG],
#   [[1, 5], :on_op, "*", EXPR_BEG],
#   [[1, 6], :on_sp, " ", EXPR_BEG],
#   [[1, 7], :on_int, "10", EXPR_END|EXPR_ENDARG]]
```

Except for the second to the fourth element, I see no differences. I thought that the constants on the right would change somehow.

Now with `sexp`:

```
Ripper.sexp 'rand *10'
#=> [:program,
# [[:command,
#   [:@ident, "rand", [1, 0]],
#   [:args_add_block, [:args_add_star, [], [:@int, "10", [1, 6]]], false]]]]
Ripper.sexp 'rand * 10'
#=> [:program,
# [[:binary, [:vcall, [:@ident, "rand", [1, 0]]], :*, [:@int, "10", [1, 7]]]]]
```

One can see there is a big difference.

How and why is it that the expressions return a different value?

Comment: If you want an AST, try `Ripper.sexp` instead. The lexer output isn't useful.

Comment: By the way, if we take the literal question from your title "Is ruby whitespace sensitive in certain cases?", then the answer is "Of course, it is!" For example, `deffoo` means something completely different than `def foo`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` in `*10` is the [unary splat operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion), whereas in `* 10` it is an overridable binary operator (in this case resolving to [`Float#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Float.html#method-i-2A)). We can see from the AST as well that, adding parenthesis, the expressions’ equivalencies are:

- `rand *10` is the same as `rand(*10)` is the same as `rand(10)`.
- `rand * 10` is the same as `(rand) * (10)` is the same as `rand.*(10)`.

This can also be confirmed at runtime:

```
def args(*args); p args; end

args *10  # prints [10]
args * 10 # prints []
```

Comment: More generally, for `n.abs > 1`, `rand(*n)` is the same as `rand(n)`, where `n.kind_of?(Numeric) #=> true`. For example `rand(*10)` is the same as `rand(*-10)`, `rand(*10.8)` and `rand(*Rational(-29,3))`. See [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand).

Comment: `*10` as a method argument is clearly the same as `10`, but I don't understand how the unary splat works here. I thought any object that responds to `to_a` can be splatted, but `10.respond_to?(:to_a) #=> false`. Please explain.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Re #1: yes; I didn’t bother to go into the semantics of `rand` as the question was about syntax. Re #2: Splat in an argument list will call `to_a`, but if the object doesn’t respond to `to_a`, the splat is just the object itself.